# Restore utility error

Tags: backup, backup-restoration, restore, windows-sbs-2011, windows-sbs-2003

I want to restore a .bkf file created on SBS 2003, to a SBS 2011. I have downloaded and instaled restore utility, but I am getting this error

> Unable to write data to c:\foldername This security id may not be
>   assigned as the owner of this object

This is not happening to all files and directories, and I would like to know how to solve this problem? I have added user as as member of Backup Operators , but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, try to start the utility via right-click, 'Run as Administrator' and see if that resolves the issue. With UAC & server 2008, all administrator accounts except for the original 'default' administrator account actually run as a standard user and require elevation. Other options to try are to disable UAC (not recommended), or browse to the folder via the admin network share (\servername\c$\foldername) when setting the output path in the Restore utility.

If I recall correctly, the SBS2011 setup makes you create a secondary/new administrator account as a best-practice thing, so you will probably run into this a lot when dealing with folders, especially with one at the root of C:.

Some more info (written for Win7, but applies):
http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/05/11/windows-access-denied-folder-administrator/

> Hi,
>   Start from Windows Vista/Windows 2008, UAC is added which help increase the security level.
>   If UAC is enabled, all accounts belong to Administrators group (except Administrator account) are actually running as a standard user. They have permission to "run as administrator" when need to access/modify system files and/or registries.
>   Thus if we only add Administrators in NTFS permission, only Administrator account can access the file without "run as admin". The workaround is to disable UAC (not recommanded) or create a new group with all administrator accounts and add the group to NTFS permission as well.

Per: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverfiles/thread/1ea6cdc7-1e19-48e0-961e-96dfd0f13ed0